# Keras W_constraint and W_regularizer analogues in Julia's Flux

Tags: keras, julia, flux.jl

I am trying to parse `Keras` json file to create a `Flux` model in Julia (`Keras` v1.1.0 and `Flux` v0.10.4).

Example of a `Dense` layer configuration:

```
{
    "class_name": "Dense", 
    "config": {
        "W_constraint": null, 
        "b_constraint": null, 
        "name": "dense_1", 
        "output_dim": 512, 
        "activity_regularizer": null, 
        "trainable": true, 
        "init": "glorot_normal", 
        "bias": true, 
        "input_dtype": "float32", 
        "input_dim": 4096, 
        "b_regularizer": null, 
        "W_regularizer": {
            "l2": 0.0010000000474974513, 
            "name": "WeightRegularizer", 
            "l1": 0.0
        }, 
        "activation": "relu", 
        "batch_input_shape": [null, 4096]
    }
}
```

So, it is clear for me how to define input/output dimensions, activation function and parameter initialization in `Flux`. But what about `W_constraint` and `W_regularizer`? I have not found any similar thing in `Flux`'s `Dense` layer. Does it exist? Should I implement it myself? Are those parameter of the `Dense` layer even important at all, or can be easily skipped when creating a `Flux` model without severily altering the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [regularization values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Tikhonov-regularized_least_squares) are norms that are summed for all parameters of the network and added to the loss function; you have to do that "manually", but it's quite easy and [described in the docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/regularisation/).

Parameter constraints in Keras are [appearently implemented](https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/) by using projection methods, which are part of the [optimizer](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/optimisers/).  That is less trivial to implement, I suggest reading a bit about proximal gradient methods.  You probably have to implement your own optimization type doing that in Flux (ideally, wrapping a one of the existing ones).  Maybe [ProximalOperators.jl](https://github.com/kul-forbes/ProximalOperators.jl) can do some of the heavy lifting.  On the other hand, models with parameter constraints are, as far as I have seen, much less common, and you might get away just leaving them unimplemented for now.

Comment: The more I am thinking about this implementation of regularization, the more confused I get since I still have very limited understanding of how Julia works. So, my module would parse a JSON and create a corresponding Flux model. However, loss if not part of the model and would be created externally as eg. `loss(x, y) = crossentropy(m(x), y) + sum(norm, params(m))`. In which format would I return this `sum(norm, params(m))` so it can be added to the user-defined loss (in some external script)?

Comment: Specifically, I am afraid that if I just calculate somehow `sum(norm, params(m))` it would just add the sum of initial weights of the model to the loss function instead of actually recalculating this sum when the weights are being changed during the training.

Comment: You could create a map from parameters to regularizers, and then just sum them up in the loss function; something like `sum(reg[param].lambda * norm(param, reg[param].p) for param in params(m))` (but I don't actually know Flux...).

Comment: Or one closure per parameter: `sum(regularizers[param](param) for param in params(m))`